# CloudStack and GPU support

Tags: vmware-esxi, cloud, gpu, cloudstack

Is there any document for GPU and VGPU support in cloudstack version 4.14 and later? For example how I find out CloudStack support Nvidia Quadro RTX series or not?

Comment: IIRC CloudStack relies first  on the underlying hypervisor for GPU support, and then it needs  be supported from CloudStack as well.  For example for Xen the support has been there since version 4.4 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLOUDSTACK-4762  and http://qa.cloudstack.cloud/docs/WIP-PROOFING/pr/265/adminguide/virtual_machines.html#assigning-gpu-vgpu-to-guest-vms

Comment: Thanks, our hypervisor supports this GPU and VGPU model, but I am not sure how to verify it is supported from cloudstack.

Comment: This is much needed feature in cloud stack. This has been referred to XenServer and that ptoduct pretty much became a paid product from Citrix.